# Where did clouds obscure the American eclipse of August 2017?

Tags: meteorology, clouds, sun

Emphasis here is *did*.

I'm trying to find a **source that will inform me about which locations in the United States *actually* had their view of the eclipse on Aug 21, 2017 obscured by clouds**.

- I'd preferably like a visual source or a compiled list of cloud covers, though compiled anecdotal accounts would be interesting, too.

I'd found a number of sources for predicting/forecasting/modeling potential cloud cover *before* the eclipse, which I used to keep my eclipse traveling/viewing plans fluid until the morning of Aug 21. However, I can't seem to find a source that shows me what the cloud cover *actually* looked like across the path of totality (and elsewhere). Essentially, I want to know how many of my dozens of changing planned destinations would or would not have worked out.

- With so many planned destinations that changed due to changing forecasts, perhaps it would be best to have a cloud cover *map* (vs. lists or personal accounts).

I'm most interested in knowing **cloud cover during actual *totality*** *across the path of totality*. If this is too much to ask, then I'd narrow that search to the Southeastern US (NC, SC, TN, GA).

Where can I find such data?

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful. In Albuquerque, the first part of the eclipse was covered by overcast, we then saw the max eclipse through the clouds, and got an unobscured view of the sun about 10 minutes after max eclipse.

Comment: Viewing angle and cloud position will be difficult to ascertain.  If you limited it to some fraction of cloud cover during the eclipse, that would be something that could be answered.  As written it is a very tough question, especially since many locations could've had scattered clouds that didn't block the view of the eclipse.